# python not executed and code is shown literal in the page

Tags: python, python-2.7, webserver

In ubuntu 12.04 i have this basic http server:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

And this file demo.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print """\
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

However when I open: http: //127.0.0.1:8000/demo.py

i receive a page with the demo.py literal in the browser. Obviously what is expected is hello world.

What is the problem? any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleHTTPServer` can only serve static pages, not CGI scripts. You could use [`CGIHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html) instead.

Use this *only* for local testing setups; these servers have hardly been battletested on the wider web and are almost certainly not secure.

Comment: can you provide an example how to serve static pages please?

Comment: The module *already* serves static pages. But it should only ever be used for a very quick developer setup to serve local pages, not for production.